# Assign value to array if first expression returns an error in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, cat

I'm not really got at shell and stumbled upon this problem

I have an array with folder locations and an array with the values I'm trying to get for those, the folders come and go though, so sometimes, when I run the check to get their associated values, the folder isn't there anymore.

I want to hide the error that cat returns when the folder is non-existant and be able to give another value to the variable.

After trying to dig a bit, I came up with this, it doesn't work but nothing I've been trying seems to either:

```
userName[i]={ "$(cat "/mainFolder/${userCodes[i]}/name")" } || { "$errorValue"; }
```

Cat throws the No file or directory error when it fails and "$errorValue" throws ": -1: command not found"

Comment: What is actually in the file? You might want something like `IFS= read -r 'userName[i]' < /mainFolder/.../name` instead.

Comment: @chepner, if you know how to suppress the "No such file or directory" warning in case of missing file (that would be thrown by `<` operator), please provide an alternative answer. Your variant should have performance advantages over mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like what you're looking for:

```
userName[i]=$(cat "/mainFolder/${userCodes[i]}/name" 2>/dev/null || echo "$errorValue")
```

`2>/dev/null` hides the error message from `cat`, while `echo` provides default value.

**Update:**

> "$errorValue" throws ": -1: command not found"

This is because bash interpolates the value of your variable and uses its value like the name of the command. You can try the following to see what I'm talking about:

```
some_var='echo'
"${some_var}" 'Hello!'
```

This will print `Hello!` to console.